# What is keras.layers vs keras.layers.core?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I've been learning basic machine learning from deeplizard.com, and had a question about something they wrote in their tutorial. On one page, we imported Dense as follows:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
```

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense
```

What's the difference between both?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same thing.

There is a [statement](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/__init__.py#L104) inside `keras.layers` `__init__.py`:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense
```

.. which making it so you can now import `Dense` directly from `keras.layers`.
`keras.layers.core.Dense` is just a fuller path to the same definition.